# JavaScript - making my regular expression work

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, expression

I have these 2 expressions:

```
1: [^a-zA-Z0-9]

2: [^a-zA-Z]
```

The first one must be used whenever my string starts with **data-** and the second one if it doesn't. However, I need this built-in into my regular expression *(so using .slice(0, 5) == "data-" is no option for this situation).*

Is it possible to do this inlined (so by just having to use 1 regular expression)? Or do I first have to validate (if string starts with **data-**) and then use the correct expression?

**Some examples:**

```
data-attribute@!#!19  => data-attribute19
data-attribute17      => data-attribute17
attribute19           => attribute
attribute1@!#!@#183   => attribute
```

Comment: please add some test strings and the wanted result.

Comment: @NinaScholz I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something a bit like this:

```
/^(data-[a-zA-Z0-9]+).+?(\d*)$|^([a-zA-Z]+).+$/
```

Which will match what you want, and then return the results inside either one or two capture groups (depending on which option it matches).

**Breaking it Down**

Going from left to right:

The `^` character means "beginning of line" - in this case, the beginning of a single string.

The parentheses `()` indicate a *capture group* - some substring that you want to capture and output separately from your main match string.

`data-` indicates the literal string "data-", with the hyphen at the end.

`[a-zA-Z0-9]+` is a character class, repeated one or more times.

`.+?` is one or more of any characters, matched *lazily* - meaning it will "give up" some of its match to enable the next token to match as much as possible.

`\d*` means zero or more digits (equivalent to `[0-9]*`).

The `$` character means "match the end of the line" (again, in this case, the end of your string).

The `|` character means "alternate" - basically, it will match *either* the pattern on the left or the pattern on the right, enabling this single regex to match either of your two strings.

Comment: Thank you for your time. You forgot adding the **0-9** range in the first expression (which is no problem at all ofcourse), but even though adding this range, it wouldn't complete my desired outcome. Take a look at this fiddle: https://regex101.com/r/qQ5qM4/1 . It's coming very very close, but only has to filter out the characters not allowed.

Comment: It should be fixed now. Then you can access the bits you want and put them together manually from the capture groups.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks! Mind giving me a short explanation of what you changed / the expression does?

Comment: I added a simple explanation of the different components.

Answer (score 0):

```
str.replace('/[@!#]/', '')
str.match('/^data-(.+)$/') // Contains true or false
```

This should do the trick.

First we remove every special chars (you can add your own.)

`[abc]` is a class of characters, wich says to JavaScript : **match any of the characters between square brackets**

Then we test if it matches with `data-attribute`

`^` and `$` match beginning and end of the input (it can't start or end with a space or any other character)

`()` catches the characters inside them. You can access what was catched with `RegExp.$1-9`

`.` means any characters, excepts line terminators.

`+` is a quantifier for **1 time or more**. It is the same as `{1,}`.

You just have now to test if it matches with the input. If it matches the attribute starts with `data-`